# Configuring web.config for two different sites of same application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, owin

I have two urls of my application,suppose url/site1 and url/site2.
On url/site1 we have implemented Ad authentication and url/site2 has application login for external users. Now there some attributes in web.config due which i'm having separate deployment folder each mapped to /site1 and /site2 under default website. I want to maintain only one set of deplyment folder . Is there a way i can configure different scenarios for each of this websites under same web.config.Mainly these 4 lines given below will have different values for each site, how can i accommodate it in same web.config so that i can keep only one deployment folder mapped to each of these sites in IIS manager.

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/>
<add key="VirtualDirectory" value="/XYZ"/>
<add key="SiteName" value="XYZ"/>
<defaultDocument>
           <files>
                <clear />
               <add value="UserLogin.aspx" />
           </files>
        </defaultDocument>
```

Comment: if I did not misunderstood you want to configure your web.config file two different membership provider?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470198/with-asp-net-membership-can-a-multiple-membership-providers-be-used-for-login-t

Comment: I want to have a only one deployment folder for both sites. As of now due to few different requirements of each site I'm having two different deployment folder with same dll, aspx,etc just different web.config.I want to know how I can keep two sets of configuration within same web.config for each sites particularly the lines that are different for each site.